# What are the names for Magic's different deck colour splashes?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Occasionally, a deck becomes famous which is a [colour combination](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11550/what-are-the-names-for-magics-different-colour-combinations) + a 'splash' of another colour.

One good example is 'Moist Jund', which is Jund (Black, Red and Green) plus a small amount of blue (which gives the Moist part of the name).

What are the names of the other splashes? That is, splashing for White, Black, Green and Red.

Comment: You'll be happy to know I've added a portion to my four-color section answer on this (I had some other edits I meant to do recently anyway - can you believe I had the three color combinations OUT OF COLOR ORDER?! HERESY!!) - I'm aware of Dark Jeskai for adding Black, and Wet Jund has been around as long as I can remember, but I was unable to find something  for splashing any other color. I have no qualms about adding it to a four color section if we can find reasonable references for the other colors. There should in theory be 20 of them - 10 three color combos with 2 each of a splash.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say the realistic answer to the question is "those terms are not commonly used". Looking back through some recent tournament decks on the official Wizards site:

- [Simon Görtzen's Boros-splash-blue-splash-black deck at the October 2020 League Weekend](https://magic.gg/league?activeLeague=ePxsGwEv75LcohyKuElmt&activeEvent=1cLOzYtDjiBh29yN9kACyc&activeTab=decklist) is simply described as "Four-color Cycling"
- [All the Temur-splash-white decks in the Top 8 at the October 2020 Season Grand Finals](https://magic.gg/events/2020-season-grand-finals) are described as "Omnath Adventures" after their namesake card, [Omnath, Locus of Creation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmnath%2c%20Locus%20of%20Creation%5d).
- [The Temur-splash-white decks in the Top 8 at the July 2020 Players Tour Finals](https://magic.gg/events/players-tour-finals-online-july-2020) are described as "Four-color Reclamation".

Comment: That seems reasonable!

Comment: This might be the case recently, but there were a number of these 4-color decks back in Khans of Tarkir block that used these sorts of names.

Comment: @nick have you considered writing an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Several years ago there was a Jeskai deck splashing Black which players christened "[Dark Jeskai](https://www.mtggoldfish.com/deck/330449#paper)".

Nonetheless, as Philip Kendall wrote, the names are not standard, and "four color" is the most common way to describe these decks.